# Java - deserialization into dynamic nested generic types with ObjectMapper

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I am writing a general JSON deserialization, using ObjectMapper (of com.fasterxml.jackson library)
The functions receives the objects type and the Collection/map type as parameters.

This is my code:

```
// Reading a single object from JSON String
public static <T> Object readObjectFromString(String string, Class<T> type) {
    try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(string, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }
}

// Reading a Collection object from JSON String
public static <T> Object readCollectionObjectsFromString(String string,  Class<? extends Collection> collectionType, Class<T> type) {
    try {
            CollectionType typeReference =
                    TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(collectionType, type);
            return objectMapper.readValue(string, typeReference);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }
}

// Reading a Map object from JSON String
public static <T> Object readCollectionObjectsFromString(String string, Class<? extends Map> mapType, Class<T> keyType, Class<T> valueType) {
    try {
            MapType typeReference =
                    TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructMapType(mapType, keyType, valueType);
            return objectMapper.readValue(string, typeReference);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    }
}
```

But What if the user needs to deserialized a complicated nested generic object, something like:

```
Map<A,List<Map<B,C>>> nestedGenericObject1
List<Map<A,B>> nestedGenericObject2
Map<List<A>,List<B>> nestedGenericObject3
// etc...
```

How to implement it as a general selution?

Comment: Side note : why are you returning `Object` from your methods instead of `T` for example for your `readObjectFromString`. Right now those methods seem pretty unusable.

Comment: What is this `ObjectMapper` type? Is it from a library? Which one?

Comment: ObjectMapper from com.fasterxml.jackson library

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`TypeReference<T>`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

```java
TypeReference<Map<A, List<Map<B, C>>>> typeReference = 
        new TypeReference<Map<A, List<Map<B, C>>>>() {};
Map<A, List<Map<B, C>>> data = mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
```

---

If you want to wrap that in a method, you can have one single method such as:

```java
public <T> T parse(String json, TypeReference<T> typeReference) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
}
```

```java
TypeReference<Map<A, List<Map<B, C>>>> typeReference = 
        new TypeReference<Map<A, List<Map<B, C>>>>() {};
Map<A, List<Map<B, C>>> data = parse(json, typeReference);
```

Comment: I will need To write multi methods, one for every possible nested format: 
Map<A,List<Map<B,C>>> nestedGenericObject1, 
List<Map<A,B>> nestedGenericObject2, 
Map<List<A>,List<B>> nestedGenericObject3, 
// etc...

Comment: @ZagGol There's no need to write a method for each combination. You can create a single method that receives a `TypeReference<T>`. See my updated answer.